# Android to Wowza streaming issue

Tags: java, android, wowza

I have very rare problem.
I have split screen on my phone which consists of `SurfaceView` and `VideoView`. `SurfaceView` is used to capture video from camera and send it to Wowza server. `VideoView` is used to receive the same stream from Wowza server.

Sometimes (I can't understand how to reproduce it) streaming works as it should, but 99% of times I don't have video in stream. I've done simple html page to identify where the problem is (in sending or in receiving) and I'm sure something is wrong with receiving (because html page shows video when there is no `VideoView`.

Here is the code I use to play stream on phone:

```
                android.os.Handler h = new android.os.Handler();
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Uri wowzaUri = Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.100:1935/live/test.stream");//Uri.parse("rtmp://192.168.0.100:1935/live/test");
                        mVideoView.setVideoURI(wowzaUri);
                        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
                        mVideoView.requestFocus();

                        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.100:1935/live/test.stream"));
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mVideoView.bringToFront();
                                mp.start();
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 5000);
```

It wrapped in Handler because it's get called in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` method (when streaming starts).

PS. Everything works fine when playing video rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov .

Can anyone help me to identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility since it works with Wowza's example streaming video ( BigBuckBunny ) is that your streaming hasn't a video/audio codec that android's phone understand.

Have you check which v/a encoding BigBuckBunny is and which is the one your trying to play ?

This is the page which show the different encodings android can handle.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Another thing which would be quite helpful is to provide Android's logcat log and Wowza's logs as well.

See ya